# Remove a shape from Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am drawing simple shapes such as triangle, circles and rectangles onto an Android `Canvas` backed by a `Bitmap`.

My question is simple : is it possible to draw a circle (or any other shape) in a way that its surface will be *removed* from the draw surface ?

Comment: When you remove the shape what do you expect to appear in its place?

Comment: Before drawing shapes, I set a background color with canvas.drawColor(argb). So I expect it to be the background color, that may be transparent.

Comment: What if it overlaps another shape?

Comment: Or another shape overlaps it?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your simple question is, "No"  A bit map has no memory so you can't ask it to go back to the previous state, and a Canvas doesn't remember the operations that got it to it's current state, so you can't say "Replay all of those operations except this one."

The more complex answer is you will have to develop the code to "remember" or "replay" as described in the preceding paragraph, or you may want to switch to another way to build your image -- for example Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG)